# Cannot process argument because the value of argument "path" is not valid

Tags: powershell, shell, automation

I got a Powershell script that checks the CSV file and based on the data in CSV it creates the users in AD. 
I've declared the path is

```
    $UPN = $user.Fname.Substring(0,1) + "." + $user.Lname
   $OU = "xyz-users,DC=contoso,DC=com" 

   $usremailad=$user.Fname.substring(0,1) + "." +$user.Lname +"$dnsroot"

Try {
    if (!(get-aduser -Filter {samaccountname -eq "$SAM"})){
     $Parameters = @{
    'SamAccountName'        = $Sam
    'UserPrincipalName'     = $UPN 
    'Name'                  = $Fullname
    'Path'                  = $OU
    'GivenName'             = $Fname
    'Surname'               = $Lname

}
```

when i execute my code i get the below errors:

> Cannot process argument because the value of argument "path" is not
>   valid. Change the value of the "path" argument and run the operation
>   again.

I know it's very simple but I can't figured it out now. 
The same script worked 100% without any issues. not sure what's changed. 
[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WO8Pk.png)

Comment: please, add all the code involved to your Question. strip out what is not needed to show the problem ... but make sure to include the code in question. you don't have such shown right now ... [*grin*] ///// also, please include the full text of the error - PoSH usually has useful info in the error messages.

Comment: The code is updated.

Comment: thanks! however, there are two problems ... [1] please, DO NOT post pictures of text. post the text so folks can read it easily. [2] you did not post the actual powershell error message. what you posted is the output of a `Write-Warning` call. _please post the actual error text. it should be available in the automatic variable named `$Error` @ `$Error[0]`.

Comment: This is the actual error I get when I run the code. what are other ways I can show the errors: WARNING: [ERROR]Can't create user [Rosa Noor] : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "path" is not
valid. Change the value of the "path" argument and run the operation again.

Comment: please open the powershell ISE and enter the following >>> `Write-Warning 'This is from the "Write-Warning" cmdlet!'` <<< and then run that code. you will note that the output is from that cmdlet. _it is not a powershell error message_. instead, it is a message from some part of the code you are running. a powershell error message can be seen by running >>> `Get-ChildItem abc:` <<< you can also see the last several errors by running >>> `$Error` <<<

Comment: Thanks heaps for your reply.PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $Error
Get-ADUser : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "path" is not valid. Change the value of the "path" 
argument and run the operation again.
At C:\Users\student\Automate\test.ps1:64 char:1
+ Get-ADUser -Filter {sam -eq $$fullname}
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADUser], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDire 
   ctory.Management.Commands.GetADUser